# netplan bridge for one static interface not working

Tags: networking, kvm-virtualization, network-bridge, static-ip, netplan

I have a static ip address for interface eno1 which should become a bridge for kvm/qemu. My netplan configuration (Ubuntu 18.04) for the static ip looks like this and is working:

```
network:
  version: 2
  #renderer: NetworkManager
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
      addresses: [XXX.XXX.196.33/20]
      gateway4: XXX.XXX.192.254
      nameservers:
        addresses: [XXX.XXX.192.80]
```

Unfortunately my bridge configuration is not working for that interface. After applying I cannot route.

```
network:
  version: 2
  #renderer: NetworkManager
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
  bridges:
     br0:
       dhcp4: false
       dhcp6: false
       interfaces: [eno1]
       addresses: [XXX.XXX.196.33/20]
       gateway4: XXX.XXX.192.254
       nameservers:
         addresses: [XXX.XXX.192.80]
```

Routing looks like:

```
# route -n
Kernel-IP-Routentabelle                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
Ziel            Router          Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface                                                                                                                                                                                                  
0.0.0.0         XXX.XXX.192.254   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 br0                                                                                                                                                                                                    
XXX.XXX.192.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U     0      0        0 br0                                                                                                                                                                                                    
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
```

---

Now I tried an additional NIC for the bridge with dhcp but failed too:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  #renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
      optional: true
      addresses: [XXX.XXX.196.33/20]
      gateway4: XXX.XXX.192.254
      nameservers:
        addresses: [XXX.XXX.192.80]
    enp4s0:
      dhcp4: true
  bridges:
     br0:
       dhcp4: true
       dhcp6: false
       optional: true
       interfaces: [enp4s0]
```

**ip addr** shows me that the interface for the bridge is always down!

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp4s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0a:cd:20:b6:05 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f0:79:59:db:e1:76 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet XXX.XXX.196.33/20 brd XXX.XXX.207.255 scope global noprefixroute eno1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::f279:59ff:fedb:e176/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: br0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 06:62:fa:ee:f8:c2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:a4:3b:8b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: virbr0-nic: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master virbr0 state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:a4:3b:8b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

I do not get any error messages when starting

```
ip link set enp4s0 up 
ip link set br0 up
```

but all NIC are still down.

What is wrong?

---

---

Ok, finally I got it working! The configuration above for setting up bridges is correct!

I missed that bridges get a new MAC address and our NAC prevented delivering an IP for that MAC because my previous bridge on the same system got a different MAC address.

Comment: That looks like networkd being unable to bring up the bridge, because the underlying interface is not configured. If you add "optional: true" under 'eno1', does it then work correctly?

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately adding "optional: true" to eno1 does not change anything.